# How to make Resteasy understand map-style HTTP parameters?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I have a problem with making Resteasy understand this syntax in the context of `@FormParam` and `@QueryParam`:

```
customer[name]=John
```

This doesn't work.

This does work:

```
customer.name=John
```

Is there a way to make Resteasy accept the first parameter style?

UPDATED:

Apologies, my question was very imprecise so here is the updated version:

For example:

```
class Customer {
   public @Valid @Form(prefix="address") Address address;
}

class Address {
   public @FormParam("line1") String line1;
```

}

Customer is the top-level POJO used by resteasy to receive parameters from the client. This is how the request looks like:

```
   name=John
   address[line1]=Street 123
```

This does not work. But, this DOES work:

```
   name=John
   address.line1=Street 123
```

Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: It should work. Possibly you need to url encode the request before making it -> `customer%5Bname%5D`.

Comment: It works in the latest versions or this is something that works for long time in Resteasy?

Comment: Special characters in the query string and form data should be url encoded. Resteasy should decode it back automatically, so it matches `@QueryParam("customer[name]")`. This is not something new.

Comment: Ah, let me explain further. I have a POJO with @QueryParam("name") in it, thus customer.name=XX works. This might be the reason that it doesn't work. Does it work for you if you use something like @QueryParam("name") in a POJO?

Comment: Hmmm. I've never tried it. I'll check it when I have time later. But that's interesting. So you are saying that in 2.x.x it doesn't work, and 3.x.x version it works?

Comment: Meaning sending `customer[name]=John` will work for `@QueryParam("name")`

Comment: Can you post some more information in your post, so that we can reproduce this. Like the resource method, and model objects, resteasy version and so on

Comment: OK, I just tested it and the problem was not what I described in the original question. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I'm looking at [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/_Form.html), and it only explains support for this format `customer[name]` for `Map`s. It doesn't explain any support for the format for pojos

Comment: Unfortunately for Maps there is a bug, so data[key]=value doesn't work as well, if you map it to Map<String, String> data. I've tested this thoroughly, and had to write a custom parser to set a Map in this way where I needed it.